# Can I use speech to text google api in local django project?

Tags: google-api, speech-to-text

helpers!
I am a beginner and have not experience in integrating API and project.
I am going to use speech to text google API for my project.
So I develop the project and when it completed, I have a plan to deploy it.
....
I want to know """ Can I test google API on localhost"""
I will appreciate if you answer for me.
Regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, we can use Google API for converting speech to text on the localhost.
please follow this doc.  https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs